# Función JavaScript solo se ejecuta 1 vez

Tags: javascript

Tengo una función en JavaScript que utiliza el evento onmousedown (mantener presionado el boton con el mouse) para ejecutarse, es un simple cronometro que cuenta hacia atrás - para el evento onmouseup (levantar el boton del mouse) tengo una función que frena la ejecución del cronometro y limpia la pantalla. Todo me funciona a excepción que solo puedo usarla 1 sola vez (no tengo mucha experiencia en javascript y no se por qué sucede esto.

HTML

```
 <input type="button" value="conteo" onmousedown="updateClock();" onmouseup="clearClock();">
<span id="countdown"></span>
```

JS

```
var totalTime = 6;
var interval;
var control;

function updateClock() {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (totalTime == 0) {
            fire();
        }
        if (control != 1) {
            totalTime -= 1;
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = totalTime;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

function fire() {
    document.getElementById('countdown').style.display = 'none';
    alert("launch missile :-D ");
}

function clearClock() {
    control = 1;
    totalTime = 6;
    clearInterval(interval);
    document.getElementById('countdown').style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: lo probé y lo puedo ejecutar varias veces, tal vez sea que no visualizas el texto del span debido a que lo ocultas y nunca lo vuelves a mostrar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien lo estuve probando y me funciona varias veces lo que noto es que puede ser la lógica que estás tratando de implementar.

control no tiene valor, por tanto es **undefined**.

```
var totalTime = 6;
var interval;
var control;

function updateClock() {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (totalTime == 0) {
            fire();
        }
         //comparas si control es != 1 pero como es undefined no entra en el caso
        if (control != 1) {
            totalTime -= 1;

// esto es lo que te digo de mostrar el elemento <span>

            document.getElementById('countdown').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = totalTime;
        }
    }, 1000);
otra vez mostrar el <span>
      document.getElementById('countdown').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById("countdown").style.color = "red";
    }
    
    function fire() {
        document.getElementById('countdown').style.display = 'none';
        alert("launch missile :-D ");
    }
    
function clearClock() {
    control = 1;
    totalTime = 6;
    clearInterval(interval);
//aquí lo ocultas pero, nunca lo vuelves a mostrar
    document.getElementById('countdown').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("countdown").style.color = "green";
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu aporte @Mr SaberHagen ya voy modificarlo para tomar en cuenta tus observaciones.

Comment: Efectivamente el problema es que nunca volvía a mostrar el span pero en realidad si se estaba ejecutando, por otro lado la variable de control era para detener el contador cosa que hago con clearInterval así que la elimine y deje un else - Comparto el código porque creo que sería útil, (el proposito es un simple contador que hay que dejar presionado para activar una función (en este caso por pruebas puse una simple alerta))

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente el problema es que nunca volvía a mostrar el span pero en realidad si se estaba ejecutando, por otro lado la variable de control era para detener el contador cosa que hago con clearInterval así que la elimine y deje un else - Comparto el código porque creo que sería útil para otras personas, (el proposito es un simple contador en reversa que hay que dejar presionado para activar una función (en este caso por pruebas llama a una función fire() que es una simple alerta))

HTML

```
 <input type="button" value="conteo" onmousedown="updateClock();" onmouseup="clearClock();">
<span id="countdown"></span>
```

JS

```
  var totalTime = 4;
    var interval;
    
    function updateClock() {
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            if (totalTime == 1) {
                fire();
            } else {
                totalTime -= 1;
                document.getElementById('countdown').style.display = 'flex';
                document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = totalTime;
            }
    
        }, 1000);
        totalTime = 4;
    }
    
    function fire() {
        clearInterval(interval);
        document.getElementById('countdown').style.display = 'none';
        alert("launch missile :-D ");
        // location.reload();
    }
    
    function clearClock() {
        clearInterval(interval);
        document.getElementById('countdown').style.display = 'none';
        // location.reload();
    }
```

De nuevo todo el credito para Mr SaberHagen que me saco del aprieto :-D